# How can I migrate my existing MOSS 2007 userprofiles including audiences to SharePoint Server 2010?

Tags: 2007, user-profile

We are planning to implement SharePoint Server 2010 in our orginization. Many of our in-house application are heavily dependent upon userprofiles and audience targeting.

Is there any Microsoft guideline following which we can migrate out existing MOSS 2007 userprofiles to SharePoint Server 2010?

Comment: @vivek: Remember to click the tick next to the best answer for your questions so the community is rewarded. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theres not much stuff out there regarding User Profile upgrade yet, but technet dont report any specific considerations beside if you use choice lists, you should remap these later to Managed Metadata Service tags if you choose in-place upgrade and if you use db attach (recommended) you should create MMS before so it can be mapped during upgrade.

Remember also that most of your User Profile Data probably are stored in AD or secondary data sources (BDC, now BCS).

You should recreate My Site host from scratch tho, since there is no upgrade path for My Sites (that im aware of), since it contains alot of new wiring especially for colleagues.

More info on migrating SA's
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee731990.aspx

The most important advice i can give you regarding upgrade is TEST your upgrade before you go anywhere near your production farm. Create a virtual test environment where you can do trial upgrades and pre-upgrade check etc.

You might find my [white paper](http://andersrask.spoint.me/sharepoint-2010/whitepaper-on-sharepoint-upgrade) on upgrading SharePoint 2010 usefull too.
Joel Oleson also got alot of info on his [blog](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=296) and in his [book](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d%2D183c%2D4fc2%2D8320%2Dba5369008acb&ID=341&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Esharepointjoel%2Ecom%2FLists%2FPosts%2FPost%2Easpx%3FID%3D296) (that i am co-authoring)

Im not sure regarding audiences, but as long as AD is the same you should be good. If all else fails you should be able to extract both audiences and user profile fields that are filled in by end users programmatically in for example an xml file and import fields and values again. On codeplex you will find tools for doing this between SharePoint 2007 sites that with smaller modifications should work for SharePoint 2010 as well:

SharePoint Audience Migration http://audiencemigration.codeplex.com/

Migrate User Profile values http://migrateupvalues.codeplex.com/ (by me :-)

SharePoint 2007 Shared Services Provider User Profile Property Replicator http://mossprofilereplicate.codeplex.com/

Comment: in the mean time i have been creating a user profile import/export for SP2010 using PowerShell. I will be releasing this tool soon on code gallery on TechNet script center

Comment: Is there a CodePlex project now available, only see the one for 2007 for migrating audiences when you dont want to bring over the SSP?

Comment: Anders, did you have publish the import/export using PowerShell?