# 2007 to 2010 DB Migration Questions

Tags: 2010, 2007, migration

I have created a new two-server 2010 farm and wish to perform a DB attach upgrade. I find the documentation vague, specifically as to the extent of the preparations on the new servers.

1) Per the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263026%28d=printer%29.aspx), configurations are not carried over. Does this mean that the AD and SharePoint Group accounts on 2007 farm will have to be all re-created from scratch?

2) Per the same documentation, "Create a Web application for each Web application that existed in the original environment... Use the same URL..." The SharePoint Services Provider no longer exists, so do I still need to re-create that as well? And at which point of the [process](http://zoom.it/x3tT#full) do I attach the original SSP DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurations are things like managed paths and quotas.  Those will all need to be recreated.

The SSP is not migrarted over, it is replaced by service applications that need to be configured, like search.

The only thing you database attach is the actual content databases listed in your Content Databases in the 2007 Central Admin. No other content DBs get migrated over.

Comment: Not according to this? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx#SSP

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what mentioned in the previous reply, you can migrate user profile database. There are very good articles explaining the steps for doing the same.
This would be essential if your applications depends on user profile data and its properties.

You can find more information on user profile details upgrade/migrate at:
[How can I migrate my existing MOSS 2007 userprofiles including audiences to SharePoint Server 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3626/how-can-i-migrate-my-existing-moss-2007-userprofiles-including-audiences-to-shar)

Regards
Manju